# Ruby on Rails 6. Using Bootstrap 4 tooltips with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, bootstrap-4, turbolinks

I have set up Bootstrap 4, Jquery and Popper.js through Webpacker.

The **application.js** file (app/javascript/packs/application.js):

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "bootstrap"

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
```

The **environment.js** file (config/webpack/environment.js):

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
  })
)

environment.config.set('resolve.alias', {jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery'});

module.exports = environment
```

With that settings my tooltips work fine, until I start using Ajax.
After changing the page using Ajax, tooltips stop working.

I've tried to insert the `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` code to my **js.erb** files, but I always get the '*tooltip is not a function*' error in a browser console:

```
VM26:4 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at <anonymous>:4:30
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.js:283)
    at rails-ujs.js:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.js:264)
(anonymous) @ VM26:4
processResponse @ rails-ujs.js:283
(anonymous) @ rails-ujs.js:196
xhr.onreadystatechange @ rails-ujs.js:264
```

A part of the page view with element using a tooltip:

```
...
      <td class="pl-2">
        <%= link_to @card, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, 
            remote: true do %>
          <i class="fas fa-times" id="deleteIcon" 
             data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete"></i>
        <% end %>
      </td>
...
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: And I just noticed that tooltips stop working when using pagination links (they're also do pagination through 'remote: true').

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any partial I load via Ajax can't find things from my `app/javascript/packs/application.js`. Were you ever able to figure it out?

Comment: I just started using 'tippy.js' instead of Bootstrap tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this in the future, this is how I was able to solve the problem.

I have to destroy (dispose) all the bootstrap tooltips and recreate them.
You can call this in your ajax success. In my case I'm using stimulus reflex and morphing the page so I call it in a finalizeReflex callback.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('dispose');
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Obviously a hacky way to fix the tooltips but its all I've been able to manage.